# How to pass an object as an argument which may be null at the time of build?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following **Pop up** which is essentially an `AlertDialog` with some data entry fields and two buttons. The widget tree is given below:

### ProductPurchaseForm

```dart
class ProductPurchaseForm extends StatelessWidget {
  ProductPurchaseForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _formGlobalKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      scrollable: true,
      content: FormBuilder(
        key: _formGlobalKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const DateField(
              name: 'date',
            ),
            const TextInputField(
              name: 'amount',
              hintText: 'Enter the Amount',
            ),
            FormFooter(
              formKey: _formGlobalKey,
              transaction: TransactionModel.productPurchase(
                tDate: _formGlobalKey.currentState!.value['date'],
                amount: _formGlobalKey.currentState!.value['amount'],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### FormFooter

```dart
class FormFooter extends ConsumerWidget {
  final TransactionModel transaction;
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> formKey;
  const FormFooter({
    Key? key,
    required this.formKey,
    required this.transaction,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final _databaseService = ref.watch(databaseServiceRiverpod);
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        CustomButton(
          buttontext: 'Cancel',
          buttonWidth: 300,
          onTapFunc: () {
            formKey.currentState!.reset();
            VRouter.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        CustomButton(
          buttontext: 'Add Transaction',
          buttonWidth: 300,
          onTapFunc: () => addTransactionFunction(
            context: context,
            transaction: transaction,
            databaseService: _databaseService,
            formKey: formKey,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

### addTransactionFunction

```dart
addTransactionFunction({
  required BuildContext context,
  required TransactionModel transaction,
  required GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> formKey,
  required DatabaseService databaseService,
}) async {
  formKey.currentState!.save();
  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
    final result = await databaseService.addTransaction(transaction);
    formKey.currentState!.reset();
    if (result.isError) {
      debugPrint(result.message);
      buildSnackBar(
        context: context,
        snackBarContent: 'ERROR: Please try again!',
      );
    } else {
      VRouter.of(context).pop();
      buildSnackBar(
        context: context,
        snackBarContent: 'SUCCESS: Transaction Added',
      );
    }
  } else {
    buildSnackBar(
      context: context,
      snackBarContent: 'Invalid Values',
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am using a 3rd party package called `flutter_form_builder` and using a `GlobalKey` to get values from the `FormBuilder`. As I am passing the `TransactionModel` to the `FormFooter`, I use `_formGlobalKey.currentState` which does not have any value (or is `null`) at the time when the widget is first built. This is why I am getting the red screen error of `Unexpected Null Value`.

I know why this is happening and, technically, the `TransactionModel.productPurchase` is only "used" when the `CustomButton` is pressed and that is when I am sure that the values will NOT be `null`. But because of the way this widget tree is set up, the `TransactionModel` is referenced when the `FormFooter` is built rather than when it is clicked.

Is there a better way to set up my widget tree so that I can work around this `null` error?

Comment: I don't like this kind of architecture. Probably you can somehow work It around and "glue" it. I'd much rather use some state management, e.g. BLoC, and access the current state of productPurchase only when it is really needed, instead of passing tons of arguments

Comment: @Wiktor I know what you are talking about and I have seen implementations where people use BLoC, provider, etc. to "save" the state of `TextEditingController`. That would not work for me because I have varying number of fields in several forms/popups. It would be too much of a hassle. I like the way this is done. I just have to figure out a way to get around this error.